# SSRS Texbox load background image expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I need to add background image to a text box on condition.So, I follow the steps as u see in the image.But it does not update it according to condition.

`tickReport` is the name of image that i need to load.

Any suggestions or clues.

Thanks and Regards...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Original answer removed on request*

## Edit to include actual answer:

It looks like you are trying to reference an External Image with the name of one embedded in your report? Change the `Image Source` to `Embedded` and your expression should work.

Comment: it doesn't update . (sorry for the previous image.See the updated image.)

Comment: @AslamJiffry  What do you mean by "It doesn't update?"  Does the image not load at all?  Does it not change when you have different data? Does it not change when you click on something?  Be specific and detailed if you want any help.

Comment: @AslamJiffry  Also it looks like you are trying to reference an External Image with the name of one embedded in your report?  Change the `Image Source` to `Embedded` and see what happens.

Comment: Your second comment gave me the answer. Please update the above answer by removing the image and put ur comment in the answer., Thanks.. Answer should be " it looks like you are trying to reference an External Image with the name of one embedded in your report? Change the Image Source to Embedded "

Comment: please can u remove the image and caption from the answer.Since i have updated the image, better to get rid of the image and caption..

Comment: @AslamJiffry Done